# group collide does not work on platform scroller with Pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame, program-entry-point, bullet

I following this [tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=platform_scroller.py) and I have added `class Opponent()` to `class Platform()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833327/adding-enemies-to-a-pygame-platformer). Next I have been trying to add **groupcollide_and_loop_for** to the complete code so that the opponent is removed when hit by the bullet. I have been looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356730/the-method-for-the-use-of-about-pygame-sprite-groupcollide) about using groupcollide within `class Opponent()` itself. I tried several ways to call `groupcollide` inside `def main` in `while not done` but I didn't get any results or any errors, it just didn't work.

groupcollide_and_loop_for:

```
    collided_opponents = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(opponents, bullet_list, False, True)
    for opponent, bullets in collided_opponents.items():
        for bullet in bullets:
            score += 1  # Increment the score.
            opponent.lives -= 1  # Decrement the lives.
            pygame.display.set_caption(str(score))
```

### Deploy the groupcollide and for loop above to the code below:

```
import pygame

# Global constants
bulletpicture = pygame.image.load("bullet.png") 
# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# Screen dimensions
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the bar at the bottom that the player controls.
    """

    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor function """

        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        width = 40
        height = 60
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        # Set a referance to the image rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Set speed vector of player
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

        # List of sprites we can bump against
        self.level = None

    def update(self):
        """ Move the player. """
        # Gravity
        self.calc_grav()

        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        # See if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right,
            # set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        # Move up/down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

            # Stop our vertical movement
            self.change_y = 0

    def calc_grav(self):
        """ Calculate effect of gravity. """
        if self.change_y == 0:
            self.change_y = 1
        else:
            self.change_y += .35

        # See if we are on the ground.
        if self.rect.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.change_y >= 0:
            self.change_y = 0
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height

    def jump(self):
        """ Called when user hits 'jump' button. """

        # move down a bit and see if there is a platform below us.
        # Move down 2 pixels because it doesn't work well if we only move down 1
        # when working with a platform moving down.
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2

        # If it is ok to jump, set our speed upwards
        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.change_y = -10

    # Player-controlled movement:
    def go_left(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the left arrow. """
        self.change_x = -6

    def go_right(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the right arrow. """
        self.change_x = 6

    def stop(self):
        """ Called when the user lets off the keyboard. """
        self.change_x = 0


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ Platform the user can jump on """

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """ Platform constructor. Assumes constructed with user passing in
            an array of 5 numbers like what's defined at the top of this code.
            """
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Level():
    """ This is a generic super-class used to define a level.
        Create a child class for each level with level-specific
        info. """

    def __init__(self, player):
        """ Constructor. Pass in a handle to player. Needed for when moving
            platforms collide with the player. """
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = player

        # How far this world has been scrolled left/right
        self.world_shift = 0

    # Update everythign on this level
    def update(self):
        """ Update everything in this level."""
        self.platform_list.update()
        self.enemy_list.update()

    def draw(self, screen):
        """ Draw everything on this level. """

        # Draw the background
        screen.fill(BLUE)

        # Draw all the sprite lists that we have
        self.platform_list.draw(screen)
        self.enemy_list.draw(screen)

    def shift_world(self, shift_x):
        """ When the user moves left/right and we need to scroll
        everything: """

        # Keep track of the shift amount
        self.world_shift += shift_x

        # Go through all the sprite lists and shift
        for platform in self.platform_list:
            platform.rect.x += shift_x

        for enemy in self.enemy_list:
            enemy.rect.x += shift_x

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """This class represents the bullet."""

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = bulletpicture

        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    def update(self):
        """Move the bullet."""
        self.rect.y -= 5
        # Remove the bullet if it flies up off the screen
        if self.rect.y < -12:
            self.kill()  # Remove the sprite from all sprite groups.



class Opponent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("cowboy.png") #.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.lives = 1
        self.rect.x = 50
        self.rect.y = 280
        self.change_x = 1
        self.change_y = 0
        # List of sprites we can bump against
        self.level = None

        pass
    def update(self):
        if self.lives <= 0:
            self.kill()  # Remove the sprite from all sprite groups.
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        if self.rect.x > 280:
           self.change_x *= -1
           self.rect.x += self.change_x
        if self.rect.x < 0:
           self.change_x *= -1
           self.rect.x += self.change_x
        pass


# Create platforms for the level
class Level_01(Level):
    """ Definition for level 1. """

    def __init__(self, player):
        """ Create level 1. """

        # Call the parent constructor
        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1000

        # Array with width, height, x, and y of platform
        level = [[210, 70, 500, 500],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 ]

        # Go through the array above and add platforms
        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)

        for enemy in level:
            opponent = Opponent()
            opponent.rect.x = 150
            opponent.rect.y = 280
            opponent.player = self.player
            self.enemy_list.add(opponent)

# Create platforms for the level
class Level_02(Level):
    """ Definition for level 2. """

    def __init__(self, player):
        """ Create level 1. """

        # Call the parent constructor
        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1000

        # Array with type of platform, and x, y location of the platform.
        level = [[210, 30, 450, 570],
                 [210, 30, 850, 420],
                 [210, 30, 1000, 520],
                 [210, 30, 1120, 280],
                 ]

        # Go through the array above and add platforms
        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)


def main():
    """ Main Program """
    pygame.init()

    # Set the height and width of the screen
    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Side-scrolling Platformer")

    # Create the player
    player = Player()

    # Create all the levels
    level_list = []
    level_list.append(Level_01(player))
    level_list.append(Level_02(player))

    # Set the current level
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    player.rect.x = 340
    player.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)

    # --- NEW
    bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player_list.add(player)
    opponent = Opponent()
    opponents = pygame.sprite.Group()
    opponents.add(opponent)
    score = 0


    # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False

    # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                 # Click a mouse button to instantiate a bullet.
                 bullet = Bullet(player.rect.x,player.rect.y)
                 bullet_list.add(bullet)
                 active_sprite_list.add(bullet)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.go_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.jump()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.change_x < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.change_x > 0:
                    player.stop()

        # Update the player.
        active_sprite_list.update()
 #  ----- The code commented below is what I tried in many ways
        #collided_opponents = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(opponents, bullet_list, False, True)
        #for opponent, bullets in collided_opponents.items():
        #    for bullet in bullets:
        #        score += 1  # Increment the score.
        #        opponent.lives -= 1  # Decrement the lives.
        #        pygame.display.set_caption(str(score))

        # Update items in the level
        current_level.update()

        # If the player gets near the right side, shift the world left (-x)
        if player.rect.right >= 500:
            diff = player.rect.right - 500
            player.rect.right = 500
            current_level.shift_world(-diff)

        # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
        if player.rect.left <= 120:
            diff = 120 - player.rect.left
            player.rect.left = 120
            current_level.shift_world(diff)

        # If the player gets to the end of the level, go to the next level
        current_position = player.rect.x + current_level.world_shift
        if current_position < current_level.level_limit:
            player.rect.x = 120
            if current_level_no < len(level_list)-1:
                current_level_no += 1
                current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
                player.level = current_level

        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT
        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)

        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

        # Limit to 60 frames per second
        clock.tick(60)

        # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Be IDLE friendly. If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
    # on exit.
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `print()` to see position for `opponent` and `bullet`. And I found that `opponent` never change position.

After digging in code I found you create two opponents.

- in `main()` you create `opponent` which is not added to `active_sprite_list` so it doesn't move and it isn't displayed but you use it to check collision
- in `Level_01()` you create `opponent` which is added to `active_sprite_list` so it moves and it is displayed on screen but you don't use it to check collision.

Because you check collision with `opponent` which never move so it never collide with bullet.

In `main()` you have to remove

```
opponent = Opponent()
opponents = pygame.sprite.Group()
opponents.add(opponent)
```

and use

```
#opponents = level_list[current_level_no].enemy_list
opponents = current_level.enemy_list
```

And use it also when you change level

```
current_level_no += 1
current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

#opponents = level_list[current_level_no].enemy_list
opponents = current_level.enemy_list
```

Comment: I had made several attempts using the code above before posting this question, so the existence of `opponent()` in main and `Level01()` was an oversight in turning my larger code to MWE, so, thank you for your well-explained note.  Your answer works but I don't know why the `opponent()`  is only removed after being hit 4 times, not 1 once as expected. I'm trying to understand. I just wanted to clarify this to definitely mark your answer as resolved. ThankXD! I looking to `def update(self): if self.lives <= 0: self.kill() `  and  `self.lives = 1` to 1 live and not 4 lives.

Comment: in `Level_01` you create opponent in loop `for enemy in level:` and `level` has 4 elements so you create 4 `opponents` - and it can be your problem. They all are in the same place so teoretically one shot should kill all of them but it seems one bullet kills only one of them.

Comment: ThankXD! I totally forgot about that, I appreciate the effort in pointing this out.